# C++ wxWidgets Giant Gap in Sizers (beginner)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm using horizontal and vertical boxsizers to build my GUI, and so far I've had success just adding everything to sizers using expand on each sizer, then adjusting a min or max width/height of diff elements to get what I want. I've run into a strange problem though.

There are 2 gaps in the contents of my GUI i don't understand. Here is an image:

[image]

Gap #1

I don't understand gap #1 because it seems unnecessary. The entire GUI starts out with a vertical boxsizer with 2 elements. All the contents above the red StaticText go into the top part, and the red StaticText is contained in the second element.

Among the sub-sizers in the top strip, the most height that should be required is for the "Castables" and "Lands" columns of TextCtrls. This leads me to strange gap #2...

Gap #2

This gap was not here until i set a max height for the 4 buttons above it. I've drawn purple outlines in paint so you can see how the sizers fit together (or how they SHOULD fit together unless I've made a mistake). The gap is at the start of a vertical sizer that then contains some other sizers... Before i set the max heights for those 4 buttons, the height of those 4 buttons filled this gap area exactly. When i set the max height for them, I want all of the contents below to slide up, not down.

Here is all of my code in the constructor that builds the entire GUI

```
// mainPanel
wxPanel *mainPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

// mainPanelSizer (vertical)
wxBoxSizer *mainPanelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

// progSizer (horizontal)
// contains program along top, and log window is along the bottom
// program contains 3 "columns"
wxBoxSizer *progSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
mainPanelSizer->Add(progSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// 1. DECK
// deckSizer (horizontal)
wxBoxSizer *deckSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
progSizer->Add(deckSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// castables column
wxBoxSizer *deckSizerCasts = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
deckSizer->Add(deckSizerCasts, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// castables title
wxStaticText *deckCastsTitle = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Castables", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
deckCastsTitle->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
deckCastsTitle->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
deckSizerCasts->Add(deckCastsTitle, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// castables content
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
{
    wxTextCtrl *textCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString);
    textCtrl->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, -1));
    textCtrl->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
    deckInputCastables.push_back(textCtrl);
    deckSizerCasts->Add(textCtrl, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}

// lands column
wxBoxSizer *deckSizerLands = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
deckSizer->Add(deckSizerLands, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// lands title
wxStaticText *deckLandsTitle = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Lands", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
deckLandsTitle->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
deckLandsTitle->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
deckSizerLands->Add(deckLandsTitle, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// lands content
for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
{
    wxTextCtrl *textCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString);
    textCtrl->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, -1));
    textCtrl->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
    deckInputLands.push_back(textCtrl);
    deckSizerLands->Add(textCtrl, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}


// 2. HAND
// handSizer (vertical)
wxBoxSizer *handSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
progSizer->Add(handSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// hand title
wxStaticText *deckHandTitle = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Hand", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
deckHandTitle->SetBackgroundColour(*wxCYAN);
deckHandTitle->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
handSizer->Add(deckHandTitle, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// hand content
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
{
    wxTextCtrl *textCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString);
    textCtrl->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, -1));
    textCtrl->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 25));
    handInputs.push_back(textCtrl);
    handSizer->Add(textCtrl, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}


// 3. OPTS
wxBoxSizer *optsSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
progSizer->Add(optsSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// a. OPTS INSTRUCTIONS (horizontal)
// contains buttons for things can do,
// add or remove needs, reset all, or calculate
wxBoxSizer *optsInstructSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
optsSizer->Add(optsInstructSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *addNeedButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "+ Need");
//addNeedButton->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
optsInstructSizer->Add(addNeedButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *removeNeedButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "- Need");
//removeNeedButton->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
optsInstructSizer->Add(removeNeedButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *resetAllButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Reset All");
//resetAllButton->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
optsInstructSizer->Add(resetAllButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *calculateButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Calculate");
//calculateButton->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 50));
optsInstructSizer->Add(calculateButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// b. NEEDS WRAP SIZER
// contains all the needs
wxBoxSizer *needsWrapSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
optsSizer->Add(needsWrapSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// b1. a single need we can copy to make more needs
wxBoxSizer *needsItemSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
needsWrapSizer->Add(needsItemSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// each need has 3 horrizontal components
// i. filters check area
// we'll do 3 columns of filters so 12 possible.
// this is
wxBoxSizer *needsItemFiltersSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
needsItemSizer->Add(needsItemFiltersSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// 4 filters per column: col 1
wxBoxSizer *needsItemFiltersCol1Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
needsItemFiltersSizer->Add(needsItemFiltersCol1Sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    wxCheckBox *filterCheck = new wxCheckBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "filter " + wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), (int)(i + 1)));
    filterCheck->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
    needsItemFiltersCol1Sizer->Add(filterCheck, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}

// 4 filters per column: col 2
wxBoxSizer *needsItemFiltersCol2Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
needsItemFiltersSizer->Add(needsItemFiltersCol2Sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
for ( int i = 4; i < 8; i++ )
{
    wxCheckBox *filterCheck = new wxCheckBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "filter " + wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), (int)(i + 1)));
    needsItemFiltersCol2Sizer->Add(filterCheck, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}

// 4 filters per column: col 3
wxBoxSizer *needsItemFiltersCol3Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
needsItemFiltersSizer->Add(needsItemFiltersCol3Sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
for ( int i = 8; i < 12; i++ )
{
    wxCheckBox *filterCheck = new wxCheckBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "filter " + wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), (int)(i + 1)));
    needsItemFiltersCol3Sizer->Add(filterCheck, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
}


// ii. build line (3 variations: land/land+fixing, specific card, and other
// should put in a ramp, but for now just do "land"
wxBoxSizer *needsItemBuildLineSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
needsItemSizer->Add(needsItemBuildLineSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> "("
wxButton *needsItemOpenBrackButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "(");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(needsItemOpenBrackButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> cards to draw combo box
wxComboBox *cardsToDrawCombo = new wxComboBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY);
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("1 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("2 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("3 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("4 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("5 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("6 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("7 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("8 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("9 to Draw");
cardsToDrawCombo->Append("10 to Draw");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(cardsToDrawCombo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> filters to apply (any/all)
wxComboBox *filtersApplyTypeCombo = new wxComboBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY);
filtersApplyTypeCombo->Append("Any");
filtersApplyTypeCombo->Append("All");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(filtersApplyTypeCombo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> cost colors combo
wxComboBox *filtersCostColorsCombo = new wxComboBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY);
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("Any");
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("Black");
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("Blue");
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("Green");
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("Red");
filtersCostColorsCombo->Append("White");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(filtersCostColorsCombo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> cost amount combo
wxComboBox *filtersCostAmountCombo = new wxComboBox(mainPanel, wxID_ANY);
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 1");
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 2");
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 3");
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 4");
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 5");
filtersCostAmountCombo->Append("<= 6");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(filtersCostAmountCombo, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> ")"
wxButton *needsItemCloseBrackButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, ")");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(needsItemCloseBrackButton , wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> "AND"
wxButton *needsItemAndButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "AND");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(needsItemAndButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// line item -> "OR"
wxButton *needsItemOrButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "OR");
needsItemBuildLineSizer->Add(needsItemOrButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// iii. line buttons (reset, + row below, - this row
wxBoxSizer *needsItemButtonSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
needsItemSizer->Add(needsItemButtonSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// buttons
wxButton *needsItemInlineAddButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "+");
needsItemButtonSizer->Add(needsItemInlineAddButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *needsItemInlineRemoveButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "-");
needsItemButtonSizer->Add(needsItemInlineRemoveButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

wxButton *needsItemInlineResetButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "R");
needsItemButtonSizer->Add(needsItemInlineResetButton, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// b2. At the bottom of all needs is a
// test control that has the build string
wxBoxSizer *needsBuildDisplaySizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
needsWrapSizer->Add(needsBuildDisplaySizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// outputSizer (horizontal)
wxStaticText *buildDisplay = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Build Display");
buildDisplay->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLUE);
needsBuildDisplaySizer->Add(buildDisplay, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


// at the bottom of the main panel stretches the log output
wxBoxSizer *outputSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
mainPanelSizer ->Add(outputSizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

// logOutput StaticText
logOutput = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Output Terminal");
logOutput->SetBackgroundColour(*wxRED);
outputSizer ->Add(logOutput, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());



mainPanel->SetSizerAndFit(mainPanelSizer);
this->Fit();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you posted, I'm not seeing gap2.  Instead, I'm seeing the buttons enlarged to fill the entire space.  I guess you changed the code slightly after the image was created.  But both the enlargement of the buttons and gap2 will have the same cause.

You have `optsSizer` which contains 2 other sizers `optsInstructSizer` and `needsWrapSizer`.  Both of those sizers are added to `optsSizer` with proportion 1.  That means that both `optsInstructSizer` and `needsWrapSizer` will be sized to have the same size.  Since the contents of `needsWrapSizer` are much larger, that means that will have gap2 in the code that generated the image.

To solve this, simply add `optsInstructSizer` to `optsSizer` with proportion 0 like so:

```
optsSizer->Add(optsInstructSizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
```

or since 0 is the default value for the proportion argument, you can just use

```
optsSizer->Add(optsInstructSizer, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
```

(I always always use 0 even though it's not necessary to explicitly remind me that the item being added has proportion 0.)  When an item is added to a sizer with proportion 0, it means that should be sized (verically in a vertical sizer or horizontally in a horizontal sizer) to its minimum size.

---

When you get rid of gap2, gap1 is removed for similar reasons.  You have `progSizer` which contains `handSizer` and `optsSizer`.  Both are added with proportion 1 which means they will have the same size.  When gap2 is removed, the vertical size `optsSizer` shrinks which removes gap1 as well since `handSizer` has the same vertical size.